# Excel - using LOOKUP() to find a value in a range defined by an INDEX() function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where I would like to model the progress of several projects over a few years.   The projects start in differing years.

I have a table with years in the horizontal axis and projects on the vertical.

[image]

I need programatically to work out in which year each project starts.  This was easy when the project line is static - I used a LOOKUP() function to connect the project number with the year number, but I would like to set-up various scenarios so that I can alter the schedule of projects on the fly from a preset list.

This was easy enough - I just set-up another table with scenarios in the vertical and the projects on the horizontal, and pulled the correct row into the main table with an INDEX() function.

[image]

However, doing this seems to have screwed-up my ability to work out what year each project starts.  The formula now gives very odd results.

Is this because I am trying to LOOKUP() inside a range which has been pulled from somewhere else via an INDEX() call?

If so, can anyone help me work out how to work around it?  I don't understand why my formula is giving me such odd results.

[image]

If you want to see the spreadsheet it's available here:

http://diggory.net/Grazing/stackExchange/Index%20of%20lookup.xlsx

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The concept is kind of complicated to grasp; Sorry if my answer won't help, but maybe try using vlookup /or hlookup?

Comment: I have tried HLOOKUP() but it gave the same results.  Sorry if I haven't explained it well enough.  I am trying to get the spreadsheet to match the year number for the project number - i.e. in the bottom screenshot for the row which has '24' I would like it to find the value '9' because in the green row the value 24 appears in the same column as the value 9 in 'year' row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
=INDEX(14:14,0,MATCH(C18,16:16,0))
```

This will return the year from the matched project.

Match will return the column number, index uses that to find the intersection of the returned column number and the row with the years.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to give the same result as my original LOOKUP() formula.

Comment: From your comment below I see you want the Year number.  I've adjusted accordingly, just need to go one row up.

Comment: The index(match()) formula appears to give the same results as my original formula - i.e. project 20 starts in year 2 (it actually starts in year 1) and that project 23 starts in year 8 (it actually starts in year 7)

Comment: It does not return that for me.  When I use the formula and change to C21 for project 23 it returns Year 7.

Comment: Ah!  Brilliant, sorry, I had somehow missed off the last argument (0) of the match function.  Thanks very much.